# Phing remove section filter

Tags: php, phing

Is there a filter, and can you give me an example of using Phing to remove a section of code?

E.g. this is my code:

```
function someFunc() {
    // <debug>
    var_dump(func_get_args());
    // </debug>
    doStuff();
}
```

How do I strip it down to:

```
function someFunc() {
    doStuff();
}
```

using Phing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out with a little regex:

```
<target name="stripblocks" depends="prepare,clone">
    <property name="stripblocks" value="debug|strict" />
    <reflexive>
        <fileset dir="${buildpath}">
            <include pattern="**/*" />
        </fileset>
        <filterchain>
            <!-- Replace the blocks using regex -->
            <replaceregexp>
                <regexp pattern="//\s&lt;(${stripblocks})&gt;.*?//\s&lt;/(${stripblocks})&gt;" 
                        replace="// &lt;$1/&gt;" 
                        ignoreCase="true" 
                        multiline="true" />
            </replaceregexp>
        </filterchain>
    </reflexive>
</target>
```

This changes

```
function someFunc() {
    // <debug>
    var_dump(func_get_args());
    // </debug>
    doStuff();
}
```

into

```
function someFunc() {
    // <debug/>
    doStuff();
}
```